# Probability of birthday

Tags: probability, pigeonhole-principle, birthday

In this years IMO a decision has been taken that each team will be consist of 10 members. What is the probability that at least two people will have a birthday on the same day of the week?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: How many days of the week are there?

Comment: There are 7 days in a week

Comment: @PritomBiswasTom hope my solution helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $10$ members. But there are only $7$ days of the week.

Hence by the [pigeon hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), the probability is $\boxed{1}$ that at least two people will have a birthday on the same day of the week.

Comment: The problem says "at least two people"